# How can we hide some of the pages wordpress until logged in?

Tags: wordpress

Pages on the Site Appear as Tabs. So Home , AboutUs , Contact us Products Services etc are pages on my wordpress site. But i want to show only few of them on the login page and rest of them only after login. Also i want to try something after login. I want to show tabs on the basis of roles as well so a role A will see 3 tabs and role b will see 5.

Comment: There's a Stackoverflow for Wordpress questions: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

page tabs are most done using [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages). so you can have a condition for your case like:

```
if(wp_get_current_user()==null)
     wp_list_pages(array('include'=>'2,34,5'));
else
     wp_list_pages(array('include'=>'2,34,5,3,6'));
```

the same applies to the role based scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Or... if it's just a temporary thing, you could do it with just CSS.

Make sure you have `body_class($class);` in your `<body>` tag.
When you are logged in, you should have a class called **logged-in**.

With that class, you can target the elements you wish to hide, and do so like this:

```
body.logged-in .tab1 {
    display: none;
}
```